# Static class variable across appdomain

Tags: c#, asp.net, static, appdomain

I am building a web server library, that to date; allows php, asp.net and of course, static content.

The main engine of this library lives inside the appdomain of the calling executable.

The library has a class 'Runtime' it's purpose is to store static properties of different types. These properties get populated from within the appdomain of the exe.

Now, the asp.net runtime requires that it lives in a separate domain, and this works without a problem

```
ApplicationManager.CreateAppDomain(typeof(ASPHost), "/", DocumentRoot)
```

BUT, from within the asp.net runtime (which is in a separate appdomain) I am not able to obtain my static properties from 'Runtime' (they are not populated when getting there values from the asp.net appdomain)

I don't have much experience with 'MarshallByRefObject', but my searches are bringing this up quite often.

Deriving my 'Runtime' class from 'MarshallByRefObject'

```
 public class Runtime : MarshalByRefObject
```

Still results in null/blank values.

Comment: `MarshalByRefObject` only works for _instances_, not _static_ data.  You possibly could create a "proxy" object that is sent to the new app domain that could "marshal" the static data across.

Comment: Thanks D, the asp.net runtime will instantiate only once during each process run, I will need to access the static properties in real time (as they may change throughout the cycle)

I'm still interested  in your approach.. could you provide an example?

Comment: Couldn't you create an instance method that calls the static ?

Comment: That's what I had done... but then overlooked the fact I am using socket references in the static class - which cant be serialized. :(

Never the less I went about it a different way.... what I needed was the endpoints being known by the ASP.NET runtime (for server variable requirements) 

IPEndpoints can be serialized (so can cross the domain barrier) I simply included them in the methods that live inside the asp.net runtime (I have a proxy class that creates a 'worm whole' in to the asp.net domain

Answer (score 0):

Well that was a blowout.

I'd overlooked the fact I have a dictionary of Sockets in my Runtime class, so even if I were to solve this... I will still have a problem of passing objects of this type.